# PHP delete value from array if var is found in the value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
   [0] => aaaaa
   [1] => bbbbb
   [2] => ccxcc
   [3] => ddddd
)
```

I want do delete every value of the array that contains the letter x, so this would be the outcome:

```
Array
(
   [0] => aaaaa
   [1] => bbbbb
   [2] => ddddd
)
```

How would I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
$output = array_filter($input, function ($v) { return strpos($v, 'x') === FALSE; });
```

If you are using PHP < 5.3.0:

```
function filter_x($v) { 
    return strpos($v, 'x') === FALSE; 
}

$output = array_filter($input, 'filter_x');
```

Comment: Yes! Got to love `array_filter`

Comment: Thanks, I use PHP < 5.3.0 though

Comment: One could use `use` to make the filter callback function a bit more flexible. Like: `function ($val) use ($char) { return strpos($val, $char) === false; }`.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array as $k => $v) { // Loop the array
  if (strpos($v,'x') !== FALSE) { // Check if $v has a letter x in it
    unset($array[$k]); // Delete the element
  }
}
array_merge($array); // Put the remaining keys in a contiguous order
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if(strpos($array[$i], 'x') !== false) {
        unset($array[$i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: DaveRandom's idea was better as it arranged the array with array_merge but still thanks!

Comment: Yeah, totally missed that you wanted the array reindexed :P